# Friction in opposite directions on a rotating disc

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, friction

A disc with radius R rotates at constant angular velocity $ω$. At time $t=0$ a person steps onto the disc at point $A$ and moves at constant velocity $V$ (with respect to the rotating framework) to point $P$, half way along line $AB$,  as shown on the picture. Line $AB$ is located distance $L$ from the center of the disc.

I am wondering whether the Force of Friction which is responsible for moving the person from $A$ to $P$ would be identical to the force of friction in case the person where to walk back from $P$ to $A$.

[image]

Comment: Well what do you think? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Sorry, it will not convert my last formula into reading format in my last comment. I hope it is still intelligible...

Comment: @AaronStevens
I am interested in the forces…
I have calculated that $F_f=mω^2(\sqrt{(R^2-L^2)}-Vt)\hat{x}+mω(2V-ωL)\hat{y}$. 

My doubt is whether on the way back it would be $F_f=mω^2(\sqrt{Vt})\hat{x}-mω(2V+ωL)\hat{y}$ or $F_f=mω^2(Vt-\sqrt{(R^2-L^2)}\hat{x}-mω(2V+ωL)\hat{y}$. In the latter case they would be identical; in the former case they would not.

Comment: Ok, I have edited your question accordingly, since your word usage has already lead to some confusion

Comment: Sorry about that!

Comment: Just employ the same techniques you used in the first case for the second case

Comment: My doubt is where to take the starting point: 0 or $\sqrt{(R^2-L^2)}$. I cannot quite figure it out on my own.

Comment: You have not shown any of your work, so I really have no clue what you are doing or how to tell you what you should do.

Comment: @AaronStevens
It is far too long to be typed out, but is there any other way I can show it to you (e.g. as a picture)?

Answer (score 1):

If we look at it from the viewpoint of work done, as you cleverly suggested, I assume it would be different: moving from A to P puts you deeper in the potential of the rotation's energy (forgive my making up the terms), since you have to speed up your own rotation to remain stationary in the disk's frame of reference as you come closer to the center.

Comment: Yes, I do. I have calculated the work done by the friction to be $F_f=mω^2(\sqrt{(R^2-L^2)}-Vt)\hat{x}+mω(2V-ωL)\hat{y}$. My doubt is whether on the way back it would be $F_f=mω^2(\sqrt{Vt})\hat{x}-mω(2V+ωL)\hat{y}$ or $F_f=mω^2(Vt-\sqrt{(R^2-L^2)}\hat{x}-mω(2V+ωL)\hat{y}$. In the latter case they would be identical; in the former case they would not.

Comment: Please note that the OP is not actually interested in work here. Just the force

Comment: @drleprikon
My doubt is where to take the starting point: 0 or $\sqrt{R^2-L^2)$. See the comment above for the details...